# how to retain # in href of <a> tag joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

how to retain # in href of  tag joomla
When i put anchor tag as

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

for a jquery it get stripeed to relative url
   Help me to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

It's bad practice to use link elements for things that are not links, though. You should consider adding your listeners to divs or more appropriate elemetns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: i solved the issue by removing href="#" attribute from <a> tag thanks for your reply